# Problems with android emulator. Doesn't update changes in xml files

Tags: android

I've a little truble with android emulator, when I change (for example) string on strings.xml, I rebuild my app, but when I run the app into android emulator, App runs with my old strings and is not updated with the new data.

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Delete the Emulator and create new Emulator and check the problem exists or not

Answer (score 1):

you need clean build
If you only modify the xml files or other resource files, I think the eclipse will not rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Eclipse isn't rebuilding the code. Check to make sure you have "Build Automatically" checked under "Project". Try cleaning your project and refreshing it. If the problem still exists... well I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall the application and then reinstall it with the new changes , you have mad in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow those instructions:

1. Disconnect the emulator. 
   2.save the current project
   3.clean the project build directory. 
   4.Then try to run the emulator again.

Answer (score 0):

Check your app/src/main/res directory. You can have different versions of main.xml and the emulator can use the one which you even do not change anything on it. Just keep the one in layout folder and delete others. This method has fixed my problem.